# Browser loading IMG from 250 LAN servers - timeout - typical browser performance - suggestions?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome, firefox

I'm loading http://192.168.1.x:9000/testimage.png from 250 hosts all at once.  Browsers seem to limit about 5 connections at a time... Most of the hosts are not available, so the IMG load will fail... so there is a timeout involved.

I have tried various forms of IMG object, reading about how typically preloading of images is done.

For a code reference, see this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1878671/enumhosts.html

Any suggestions for speeding up the process? Would loading 10 different IFRAME and slaving them allow the browser to do more concurrent connections, etc?  JSON requests seem to take longer than IMG load, I tried that. I also tried HTTPS vs HTTP - seems to be about the same performance. Open to any ideas.

I am working only with modern browsers - namely Chrome / Firefox / Opera (based on Chromium) - and using HTML5 and also have jQuery 2.x available.  I'm also open to any browser-specific tricks if you know of one.

EDIT: I did experiment with creating 5 IFRAME objects and appending the new Image elements to the IFRAME inner document. Didn't seem to improve speed very much on Chrome 31.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is better solved by building scalability into your design in the first place.

Randomize the image path to n different paths.  Then provide n different servers for that same image.  Start with n=2 or 3, until you need more.

So rather than just solve the problem of today's performance, you will have solved today's problem and your future problem at the same time.

Obviously this will only work for static loads, like fixed images, or css or js pages.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the need. The goal is to test 250 IP Addresses as quick as possible - seeking out tricks and tips to do this. It isn't about changing the application. This is not a typical use of a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this to test something on the servers?  Maybe there is just a better way to do this.  Are these real servers or workstations running a web servers?  Sometimes various networking items such as switches may be throttling back your speed when it sees a lot of activity and causing the time outs.

Comment: It's entirely on a LAN - for discovery of a server. Think of it this way: a javascript WebApp wants to find your router. It's a JSON Discovery Service.  It works, but I'm trying to find a trick of how to speed it up.

I haven't actually tried the IFRAME idea. Launching 10 different browsers at the same time... I was hoping someone here had some experience to share in that area or similar ideas.